# macOS Sierra FontBook displays question marks in box

Tags: macos, fonts, macos-sierra

**Problem:** I don't know when it started but FontBook in macOS Sierra Version 10.12.1 displays question marks in box for some fonts such as `STIXIntegral*` and `Symbol*`, even though they are validated clean. More standard ones such as `STIXGeneral` are displayed correctly.

**What I have tried:** I have tried deleting `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontBook.plist` and reloading Fontbook. I also tried clearing font cache by `sudo atsutil databases -remove` and logging out and logging back in. Nothing worked. The Guest account is the same. What else could I do?

[image]